# I need help for transforming this query into Laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

If you please, I need some help for transforming this query into Laravel's query builder:

```
SELECT
      DATE(created_at) AS Date,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `Type` = 'Votes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Votes',
      SUM(CASE WHEN `Type` = 'Users' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Users'
    FROM
    (
        SELECT created_at, 'Votes' `Type` FROM votes
        UNION ALL
        SELECT created_at, 'Users'        FROM users
    ) t
    GROUP by DATE(created_at)
    ORDER by DATE(created_at) DESC
```

Can someone help me please?
Thanks!!

================================================================

**Update:**
Actually my problem is on this code:

```
public function getVoteResult($topic_id){
        if($topic_id==null || $topic_id == ""){
            return null;
        }
        $topic = VoteTopicModel::select('*')->where('topic_id', $topic_id)->first();
        $choice = VoteChoiceModel::select('choice_id', 'name')->where('vote_topic_id', $topic_id)->get();
        
        foreach($choice as $choices){
                $choices['count_result'] = VoteChoiceSubmitModel::select('*')->where('vote_choice_id', $choices->choice_id)->count();
        }
        $data = array('topic_id' => $topic_id, 'topic_name' => $topic->name, 'topic_title' => $topic->title, 'choice' => $choice);
        return $data;
    }
```

It's working perfectly but, as you can see I called three tables `VoteTopicModel`, `VoteChoiceModel`, `VoteChoiceSubmitModel` which are not really effective. So my friend said try using that query for that, but I don't really understand.

Thanks in advance!! for helping me...

Comment: Do you have any code where you have tried to write this in Laravel's query builder?

Comment: I've updated my question. Thanks in advance! @WillWalsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query looks very large to convert quickly to query builder but in simple way you can do this.

```
  DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT
  DATE(created_at) AS Date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `Type` = 'Votes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Votes',
  SUM(CASE WHEN `Type` = 'Users' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Users'
  FROM
    (
     SELECT created_at, 'Votes' `Type` FROM votes
     UNION ALL
     SELECT created_at, 'Users'        FROM users
    ) t
  GROUP by DATE(created_at)
  ORDER by DATE(created_at) DESC") )
```

Comment: Whoaa.. I see... Thanks for the answer! @Prashant